# vagrant Berkshelf berksfile_path

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, berkshelf

I have a cookbooks folder in root project which also has the Vagrantfile.
I only have a couple of cookbooks (starter depends on **"apt"** and database depends on **mysql**). These cookbooks were generated with berks cookbook.

Now problem is when it comes to set the *config.berkshelf.berksfile_path* in the Vagrantfile, I don't know if put *./cookbooks/starter/Berksfile* or *./cookbooks/database/Berksfile* since both cookbooks have berks dependencies.

I tried multiple options like move these cookbooks into **cookbooks-src** and iterate through each of them and execute **berks vendor ../../cookbooks** but didn't work since the second vendor generated cookbooks would overwrite previous one.

Tried also vendor each cookbooks dependencies into *./cookbooks/the-cookbook/cookbooks* but vagrant doesn't recognize them.

This is my vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.hostname = "chef-DK"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "67"]
    v.memory = 537
  end

  config.berkshelf.enabled = true
  config.berkshelf.berksfile_path = "./cookbooks/starter/Berksfile"
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.install = false  

    chef.run_list = [
      'recipe[starter::default]',
      'recipe[database::default]'
    ]
  end
end

project/
├── cookbooks/
│   ├── database
│   │         ├── recipes
│   │         ├── Berksfile
│   │         └── metadata.rb
│   └── starter
│             ├── recipes
│             ├── Berksfile
│             └── metadata.rb
└── Vagrantfile
```

============================================

content of starter/metadata.rb:

```
name             'starter'
maintainer       'YOUR_NAME'
maintainer_email 'YOUR_EMAIL'
license          'All rights reserved'
description      'Installs/Configures starter'
long_description 'Installs/Configures starter'
version          '0.1.0'

depends 'apt', '~> 3.0.0'
```

content of starter/Berksfile:

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

metadata

cookbook 'apt', '~> 3.0.0'
```

============================================

content of database/metadata.rb:

```
name 'database'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'all_rights'
description 'Installs/Configures database'
long_description 'Installs/Configures database'
version '0.1.0'

depends 'mysql', '~> 6.0'
```

content of database/Berksfile:

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

metadata

cookbook 'mysql', '~> 6.1.3'
```

Comment: Could you add the output of your `Berksfile`s and the `depends` in your `metadata.rb` files? just to check that you don't have any unusual dependence. Probably you will need to create another third Berksfile that includes the other two cookbooks.

Comment: I just added what you requested to the main question.
I tried to add a berksfile in the root folder where these couple of cookbooks are located but then vagrant would complain that there is no metadata.rb next to the berksfile.
I tried a workaround which actually work but is not what I'm looking for. I just put in my starter/berksfile a dependency to ther database cookbook through path attribute and also move all dependencies of the database/berksfile into starter/berksfile and finally vendor starter cookbook but again this is not what I'm looking for when it actually work as I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to clarify that the berkshelf `metadata` instruction reads the cookbook *metadata.rb*  (i.e., your `cookbook` entries in your *Berksfile*s seem redundant).

In your case you could create a **Berksfile** in you main *project/* directory (next to your *Vagrantfile*) with the following content:

```ruby
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

cookbook 'database', path: 'cookbooks/database'
cookbook 'starter', path: 'cookbooks/starter'
```

And then add it to your **Vagrantfile**:

```ruby
config.berkshelf.berksfile_path = './Berksfile'
```

I think your problem is that you are adding a `metadata` instruction in your vagrant Berksfile and that's why you are getting the *"there is no metadata.rb"* error.

Comment: don't know what make you "think" in that since content of the 5 files are here.
Thanks for the tip that I could put an additional berksfile int he root next to vagrant but it still will prompt error about metadata.rb
Thanks for the tip about put relative paths to cookbooks.
I think there are workarounds but not a real solution for this. I's such small test if any could test this ? create 2 cookbooks with berks dependencies each one and try to provision a vagrant box with that. It just wont work.

Comment: I tested this before answering your question and it worked. Maybe I'm not explaining myself properly. I'm using vagrant version `1.6.5`, berkshelf version `4.3.0` and `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin version `4.1.0`. What I meant is that maybe when you tried using the *root* Berksfile you added the `metadata` instruction in it and that's why you are getting the error about the *metadata.rb*. If you don't add a `metadata` instruction it should no complain about needing a *metadata.rb*.

Comment: So should I have a blank metadata.rb file. Will try it.

Comment: No, you don't need an empty *metadata.rb*. Simply don't put a `metadata` instruction in the *root* Berksfile used by vagrant. It should not complain about a *missing metadata.rb*  if you do it that way.